System tray icon don't exist for Transmission in Ubuntu 24.04
No ability to choose show/hide system tray icon exists.

Transmission works only when opened as common application.

Why do you think this is not working as expected? Please be more specific about the problem, and why it isn't as expected. Bug reports and feature requests should be directed at the Transmission team, not here.

At previous version of Ubuntu I was able to check "Show in tray". So i decided to ask here.

In 24.04 the GTK version of transmission doesn't provide a system tray icon, please see this discussion.
You may want to use the package transmission-qt instead which provides the option for a system tray icon in the preferences window.
You could also install qbittorrent which provides a system tray icon.

a.f.a.i.k., transmission is not on GTK4

@vanadium It is in 24.04 apt depends transmission-gtk gives Depends: libgtk-4-1 (>= 4.0.0)

qbittorrent exist in tray - thank you!

@mook, that is probably in order to use the GTK4 file dialog only. The main application of the current version is most certainly GTK3. Apart from the appearance, another way to tell is that the GTK trick "GTK_THEME=Default-dark transmission-gtk" works to change the theme.

@vanadium The current version of transmission-gtk is built on GTK4, that's why it depends on lbgtk-4 but not on libgtk-3. The switch to GTK4 seems to be the reason why the application indicator doesn't exist anymore, it used to be there under GTK3. Please see this discussion.

@mook765 I see! I was judging by the appearance, which still is like before. Probably, that depend on using libadwaita or not, not on using GTK4 or GTK3. By the way, it would be good to add the link to you answer.
